# dt.last-child not working

Tags: html, css

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sWVdH/2/) where I'd like to remove the white `border:bottom` on the last child ('Headline Three').

I tried the following CSS, but it didn't work.

```
#containerr  dt.last-child {
border-bottom:none;
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `.last-child` is looking for an actual `class`, [`:last-child`](http://quirksmode.org/css/selectors/firstchild.html) is the pseudo class you are probably after...

Comment: What typo do you mean? `#containerr` is spelled correctly.

Comment: @Mathletics I wouldn't say that; It's not exactly a misspelt word.

Comment: @F4r-20 the issue is the difference between a `.` (dot) and a `:` (colon). I know it isn't a slipped key, but it's still a typo. (And as I look at my keyboard, it _could_ have been a slipped key.)

Comment: @FDL: I also tried `:last-child`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: why not just add the a `last-child` class? http://jsfiddle.net/sWVdH/5/

Comment: I rescind my vote-to-close; instead, let this be a lesson to all that you should post your markup in the question AND the demo so that jerks like me don't misidentify the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This doesn't answer you question, but provides a workaround the issue.**

I tend not to use `:last-child` (since I use to develop for older browsers - well one older browser - IE). Also I find :last-child a bit awkward to work with.

`:first-child` is more widely supported (CSS 2) so I prefer using this.

What you do is instead of adding bottom border, you add top border - so the output would be border > content > border > content

Then you use :first-child to remove the top border from the first element, so you're left with content > border > content.

I've copied your fiddle over and made this with two changes:

First, replace bottom border with top border:

```
#containerr dt {
    [...]
    border-top:1px solid white;
}
```

Second, use the `:first-child` to remove the top border from the first dt:

```
#containerr  dt:first-child {
    border-top:none;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ninty9notout/et7TW/

Enjoy!

Answer (score 10):

What you were actually looking for was `:last-child` - however this isn't implemented in the way you would expect. `:last-child` means that the element must be the last child in the parent, even if the elements that follow are of different classes/types.

What you are *actually* looking for is the [`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alast-of-type):

```
#containerr dl dt:last-of-type {
    border-bottom:none;
}
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/sWVdH/4/)

The only problem being that it isn't supported in IE before V9.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Coz, you know, we really need to stop supporting IE. :P

Comment: This is the correct answer because last-child doesn't target the last <dt> in a <dl>. But last-of-type does.

Answer (score 1):

```
#containerr dt:nth-last-child(2){
    border-bottom:none;
}
```

Try that, it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo selectors are prefixed with a colon (`:`). the `.` prefix denotes a class. Equally, `:last-child` targets the very last element within a collection. In your case, a `dd` element is the last child, so for this reason you should use `:last-of-type`. Change:

```css
#containerr  dt.last-child
```

To:

```css
#containerr  dt:last-of-type
```

[Amended JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/sWVdH/6/).

Check out the [CSS Selectors specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors) for further detail.